# Fan-hat-ic WinterBash hat is not awarded

Tags: support, winter-bash-2015

According to [WinterBash website](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com), in order to get Fan-hat-ic hat, I need to

> visit on 10 consecutive days

By now, I have been visiting Stack Overflow for 13 days in a row, which is displayed on my profile, but I still haven't received this hat.

I understand that it usually takes time to award something, but it is like three days after its completion.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Perhaps, 10 days when winter bash is active? It surely hasn't been 10 days

Comment: Oh, probably, this question should belong to Meta StackExchange, but not Meta Stackoverflow. If I am right, then I would appreciate if someone moves this question to a more appropriate forum.

Comment: Don't think there's anything wrong with the question being here.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Unless otherwise stated in the hat description, everything contributing to a hat's requirements has to have occurred *during Winterbash*. So all 10 of those consecutive days need to occur during the event.

Comment: Oh, now it sounds logical. Thank you :)

Comment: To throw my hat into the ring. I received the `Cerro de Potosi` hat for being awarded the `Yearling` badge. Yes I earned the badge during winter bash, but of course winter wash does not last all year.